# Amchart dynamically load maps with scroll

Tags: jquery, maps, amcharts

Do anyone have a clue how i can add

AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv", {   "**mouseWheelZoomEnabled**": true
});

to this example:

```
jsfiddle.net/amcharts/V7Xq8/
```

please help im desperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap) **mouseWheelZoomEnabled** is a property, so you can simply set to true this after creating the object (i.e.: map = new AmCharts.AmMap();).

So the updated code is:

```
AmCharts.ready(function() {
map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
map.mouseWheelZoomEnabled = true;  // add this line
map.pathToImages = "http://www.ammap.com/lib/images/";
```

The updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V7Xq8/256/).

Comment: Could you help me again, please? Im now struggling to make return button. When i enter specific map of the country i cant go back to the world map :(

Comment: @KonradAlbrecht fiddle updated. A "go back" label is now there whenever you jump in a submap.